# Can you recover ~/.ssh contents on AWS EC2 with an open session and keys?

Tags: linux, ssh, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh-keys

I am using AWS EC2 with Ubuntu.  I accidentally deleted the contents of `~/.ssh` but still have my session open and still have my `.pem` and public keys backed up on my PC.  Is there a way to recover my `~/.ssh` content? I tried copying my public key, pasting it into a file with the same name on my instance and entering.

```
cat my-key.pkk >> authorized_keys
```

But I cannot open another session with PuTTY.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot recover it.

But as long as you have your session open, you can re-create the `authorized_keys` the same way, you would create it for the very first time on a normal *nix system.

- create `~/.ssh` folder, and set its permissions to `700`:

  ```
  mkdir ~/.ssh
  chmod 700 ~/.ssh
  ```
- run PuTTYgen on your local Windows machine, load your key pair (`.pem` or `.ppk`) into it, copy the contents of *Public key for pasting into OpenSSH authorized_keys file* box to the clipboard;
- type `cat > ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` in your PuTTY terminal;
- right click the terminal window to paste the line copied from PuTTYgen;
- press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>;
- set permissions of `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` to `600`:

  ```
  chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
  ```

Now you should be able to authenticate a new session using your private key.

See also *my* guide for [Set up SSH public key authentication](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_public_key#configure_openssh).

Comment: It worked!  Thank you times 100.